# add and retrieve record from mysql using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image]

As shown from the diagram, I have two tables in my mysql and I would like the system to add and retrieve comment without refreshing the page.

I have three php pages involved in this function and they are 'DB.php', 'comment.php' and 'action.php'
The codes are as shown:

DB.php

```
    <?php
     $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','Practical4','1234') or die (mysql_error);
     $db=mysql_select_db('Practical4', $conn) or die (mysql_error);
     ?>
```

comment.php

```
           <----------------ajax script-------------------->

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".submit_button").click(function() {
        var textcontent = $("#content").val();
        var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
        if(textcontent=='')
        {
            alert("Enter some text..");
            $("#content").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "action.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#show").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('content').value='';
                    $("#flash").hide();
                    $("#content").focus();
                }  
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<div>

         <-----retrieve hotel id from hotel table-------->
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','Practical4','1234') or die('Not connected');

$database=mysqli_select_db($conn,'Practical4') or die('Database Not connected');

$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = "select * from hotel where name='$id'";
$data=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

    $name=$rows['name'];
    $price=$rows['price'];
    $duetime=$rows['dueTime'];
    $address=$rows['location'];
}
?>

  <---------------post form------------------->
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
<h3>Add Comment for <?php echo $name;?><h3>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" hidden > <br>
<textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="content" id="content" maxlength="145" >
</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="submit_button"/>

</form>
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="flash"></div>
<div id="show"></div>
```

action.php

```
    <?php
include('DB.php');
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment order by commentID desc");
if(isset($_POST['content']))
{
$content=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['content']));
$name=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));

mysql_query("insert into comment(content,name) values ('$content','$name')");
$fetch= mysql_query("SELECT content FROM comment order by commentID desc where name = '$name'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch);
}
?>

<div class="showbox"> <?php echo $row['content']; ?> </div>
```

when I run this, the page display nothing when I insert the comment, can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: comment is being stored into database or not?

Comment: hmm, It is not stored~but I think the sql query is correct

Comment: try changing `data: dataString,` with `data: { content: textcontent},`

Comment: you are using jquery ajax then why you need `document.getElementById('content').value='';
` and second thing add parameter `async:false` and at last you have not echo'd any content so you will not get any in success

Comment: Add error checking to your `mysql` calls: `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`.

Comment: please pass the parameter as a json format in ajax as like the above comment of @mrdeveloper and please `print_r($_POST)` in action.php to varify that you getting the param or not

Comment: @mrdeveloper I have changed that and it is still not working; @ sagar I used reference from here http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/08/insert-and-view-data-without-refresh.html ; @ kushPHP nothing printed with your statement, any idea why?

Comment: does anyone has a good example of using ajax to read and retrieve record from mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes have been made as follows:

comment.php

```
          <!-- ajax script -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".submit_button").click(function() {
        var textcontent = $("#content").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent + '&name='+name;
        if(textcontent=='')
        {
            alert("Enter some text..");
            $("#content").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "action.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#show").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('content').value='';
                    $("#flash").hide();
                    $("#content").focus();
                }  
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<div>

         <!-- retrieve hotel id from hotel table -->
<?php
include('DB.php');

$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = mysql_query("select * from hotel where name='$id'");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $name=$rows['name'];
    $price=$rows['price'];
    $duetime=$rows['dueTime'];
    $address=$rows['location'];
}
?>

  <!-- post form -->
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
<h3>Add Comment for <?php echo $name;?><h3>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" hidden > <br>
<textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="content" id="content" maxlength="145" >
</textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="submit_button"/>

</form>
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div id="flash"></div>
<div id="show"></div>
```

action.php

```
<?php
include('DB.php');
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment order by commentID desc");
if(isset($_POST['content']))
{
$content=$_POST['content'];
$name=$_POST['name'];

mysql_query("insert into comment (content,name) values ('$content','$name')");
echo '<div class="showbox">'.$content.'</div>';
}
?>
```

**Reasons why your code failed:**

- name not added in dataString causing name not sent in post
- some mysql errors

Comment: Thank you for your changes. but the comment is still not stored into mysql table, any idea why ?

Comment: Yeah~I think its because my reference is not working.  It is now working, thanks a lot! btw, If I want to use json to do the same thing, is there any difference for the above code? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience in json!